# Is it possible to have 里 and 上 placed after anything else that a noun?

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to have 里 ('in') and 上 ('on') placed after anything else that a noun (for instance after a verb)?

I can think about only:

_这里, 那里, 哪里 (two determinants and one pronoun)

_往上 , 向上,  以上,  至上  (mainly prepositions)

Answer (score 1):

Apparent里，里 is/was original里 a distance, approximately 500m

飞55000英里
120公里
加上
放上二十分钟

Comment: Thank you. I am referring mainly to 里 as a preposition meaning 'in'